# Why when the digit of the number is bigger than 4, the result is broken

Tags: c, arrays

I want to write code to add the big number, mainly idea is to array to put every digit of  the number and add two arrays in the same place. But I find the following code can only success when the digit of the number I input is smaller than 4, when it gets bigger, it turns out to input some other symbol rather than the number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void Input(char* pA, int *psizemove);
void Output(char* pA, int isize);
void Add(char* pA1, int isize1,char* pA2, int isize2,char* pAr, int *psize);
int main() {
    char pA[100] = { 0 };
    char pA1[100] = { 0};
    char pA2[100] = { 0};
    char pAr[100] = { 0 };
    int psize1[1] = { 0 };
    int psize2[1] = { 0 };
    int psize[1] = { 0 };
    int isize=20, isize1=20, isize2=20;
    int i;
    Input(pA1, psize1);
    isize1 = *psize1;
    Input(pA2, psize2);
    isize2 = *psize2;
    printf("The fisrt big number you input is:\n");
    Output(pA1,isize1);
    printf("The second big number you input is:\n");
    Output(pA2, isize2);
    Add(pA1,isize1,pA2,isize2,pAr,psize);
    i = psize[0];
    Output(pAr, i);
    return 0;
}
void Input(char* pA, int *psizemove) {
    int i;
    char c;
    printf("\nPlease input big number:\n");
    for (i = 1; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; i++) {
        pA[i] = c;
    }
    *psizemove = i;
}
void Output(char* pA, int isize) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= isize; i++) {
        printf("%c", pA[i]);
    }
}

void Add(char* pA1, int isize1, char* pA2, int isize2, char* pAr, int* psize) {
    int i, c,gap;
    if (isize1 < isize2) {
        *psize = isize2;
        gap = isize2 - isize1;
    }
    else { 
        *psize = isize1;
        gap = isize1 - isize2;
    }
        int media[100] = { 0 };
        if (isize1 < isize2) {
            for (i = 1; i <= isize1; i++) {
                media[i] = pA1[i];
            }
            for (i = 1; i <= gap; i++) {
                pA1[i] = (0+'0');
            }
            for (; i <= *psize; i++) {
                pA1[i] = media[i - gap];
            }
        }

        if (isize2 < isize1) {
            for (i = 1; i <= isize2; i++) {
                media[i] = pA2[i];
            }
            for (i = 1; i <= gap; i++) {
                pA2[i] = (0+'0');
            }
            for (; i <= *psize; i++) {
                pA2[i] = media[i - gap];
            }
        }

    for (i = *psize; i >= 1; i--) {
        c = (*(pA1 + i)-'0') + (*(pA2 + i)-'0');
        if (c <= 9) {
            *(pAr + i) += (c+'0');

        }
        else {
            *(pAr + i) += (*(pAr + i)+'0')+ ((c- 10)+'0');
            *(pAr + i - 1) = (1+'0');
        }
    }
    if ((pAr[0]-'0') == 1)   psize[0]++;
}
```

Comment: C or C++? You can't program both at the same time.

Comment: There are a couple of flaws in your program that will lead to problems. The first is that you're mixing one-based and zero-based indexing of your arrays. Zero-based indexing is the correct. The second problem is that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an `int`, which is important for the `EOF  check. Which you do not have, which means you have a possible infinite loop in the `Input` function, which will go way out of bounds of the array `pA`.

Comment: why are you using arrays of size 1 instead of `int`s?

Comment: Because I want to change it in the function I defined and do not want return something@idclev463035818

Comment: So use the address-of operator to pass a pointer to the plain `int` variable? As in `int psize1;` and `Input(pA1, &psize1);` Although it would be better to just return the value (why don't you want to do that?)

Comment: I only know when getting something from a file I should use the getchar and EOF to judge when it gets to the end of the file. Could you explain more why I should use the getchar and EOF when input from the keyboard@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: What if the input to your program will come from redirecting a file or from a pipe? Or what if the user presses the end-of-file keyboard sequence instead of the `Enter` key?

Comment: try running you a program with Debugger - especially the for loop in your add function - your main problem is there if you don't have one you can use [GBDONLINE](https://onlinegdb.com/S18LhyHnL) i allready enter your code there

Comment: Why `int psize1[1] = { 0 };` instead of `int psize1 = 0;` An array of 1-element makes little sense.